# How often is CRL refreshed, and how to force it to be?

Tags: ssl-certificate, crl

I have a web service running under IIS 7 that requires an X509 client certificate. I know that the server that it rus on needs access to DigiCert.com in order to be able to get the CRL (Certificate Revocation List).

There is a need to change our proxy so I am attempting to investigate the impact of doing so. I have removed the global proxy settings using the command `netsh winhttp proxy refesh`, and also deleted the CRL cache using the command `certutil -URLcache CRL delete`.

However, after doing this, all calls to the web service still succeed. This suggests to me that I am missing something here.

So; **If the CRL cache is cleared and the server has no way of refreshing the CRL, why do web service requets not return http 403?**.

I have been unable to find adequate information from googling nor from my colleagues.

The reason I want it to fail is that I will not be confident that the new proxy settings work until I can see it broken first, if that makes sense.

I would also like to be able to force the CRL to be refeshed in order to ensure that the new proxy settings work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but if the server has no way to check the CRL, there is no way to "revoke" the certificate.  So hence it would continue to work.  The CRL isn't an "allow" list, but rather a "deny" list.

Comment: Sounds logical but I was under the impression that if a CRL cannot be checked, cached or otherwise, then the request will be forbiden. Perhaps I was wrong?

Comment: Might be dependent on the application and how it uses the cert.  It might make sense to have it work that way in instances where the CRL might be blocked so the machines would continue to trust the cert even though it had been revoked.  say like user or machine certs used for VPN for example..

Comment: Any idea where I can see/change what 'CRL lookup' settings are being used?

Comment: if you open the certificate, you can see the CRL Distribution points in the cert.  That should show you were it is pointing.  I believe its always a URI.  For example, my company uses GoDaddy for our cert and our CRL URI is http://crl.godaddy.com/gds1-60.crl

Answer (score 0):

If the CRL cannot be reached, IIS returns a 403.13 by default.

[Source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/crl-checking-by-iis/ba-p/348170)

> IIS , by default retrieves a CRL whenever it receives a client cert to make sure that cert is not revoked as long as local cache is expired. For this it contacts the CA to get the CRL which is a list of revoked certificates and compares the list with the presented client cert. If for any reason it cannot retrieve the CRL, it will go ahead and throw error message as 403.13 even if cert is valid and not revoked.  This can happen in cases where some Proxy/firewall may block access to CDP to get the CRLs.

We all know a 403, but a 403.13 might be new to some of us, I certainly didn't know about substatus code before the start of this year!

> 403.13
> HTTP 403.13 Forbidden: Client certificate revoked
> The page requires a valid client certificate

> For an understanding of this error message check KB 248058.

> This error message means that the client sent a certificate, but either the certificate shows up as revoked in the issuing authority's Certificate Revocation List or the server could not retrieve a CRL from the issuing authority.

We can control the behavior of IIS using netsh commands on newer IIS versions, or with `certutil` commands on older versions.  There are four choices available to us for how to handle Certificate Revocation List requests.

> If CertCheckMode is set to 0, IIS does the CRL verification based on the cached CRL on the server (based on its properties like current date and ‘Next Update’ field). If the current date is in the range of ‘Effective Date’ and ‘Next Update’ fields it will use the local CRL cache. If the current date is beyond ‘Next Update’ field it will try downloading the CRL from the remote location and use it.

> If CertCheckMode is set to 1 Certificate revocation checking is not performed.

> If CertCheckMode is set to 2 Certificate revocation verification will be done based on the cached CRL on the IIS server. IIS will not try to connect to the remote server to download the CRL even if it has expired and in which case CRL verification will obviously fail.

> If CertCheckMode is set to 4 Certificate revocation verification will be done by downloading the remote CRL, even if we have the valid cached CRL on the server. It ignores the cached CRL completely.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/897708/http-error-403-13-forbidden

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-revisited-how-to-troubleshoot-client/ba-p/348053